# Printing parsed JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

Assuming this is the .JSON file I have to parse:

```
{
"item": {
    "allInventory": {
        "onHand": 64,
        "total": {
            "1000": 0,
            "1001": 6,
            "1002": 5,
            "1003": 3,
            "1004": 12,
            "1005": 0
        }
    }
},
"image": {
    "tag": "/828402de-6cc8-493e-8abd-935a48a3d766_1.285a6f66ecf3ee434100921a3911ce6c.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF"
 }
}
```

How would I go about printing the total values like:

```
1000 - 0
1001 - 6
1002 - 5
1003 - 4
1004 - 12
1005 - 0
```

I have already parsed the values, but I'm unsure of how to actually print them. I've already spent awhile on this and couldn't find a solution so any help is appreciated. Here is my code thus far:

```
import requests
import json

src = requests.get('https://hastebin.com/raw/nenowimite').json()

stats = src['item']['allInventory']['total']
print(stats)
```

Comment: And which is your problem exactly? You're printing what you want already, right?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there:

```
for item in stats.items():
    print '%d - %d' % item
```

What this does is that `stats` is already a [dict](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). Looking at the documentation, there is the `items` method which returns "a copy of the dictionary’s list of (key, value) pairs". And each pair is formatted as two numbers, i.e. `'%d - %d'`.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done through a for loop as follows:

```
for key in stats.keys():
    print(key, '-', stats[key])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using full Python 3.6 you can do (similarly than Ecir's answer)

```
for key, value in stats.items():
    printf(f'{key} - {value}')
```

but being clearer about what is the key and the value and using the f-string interpolation.

Answer (score -1):

You can try:

```
>>> import json
>>> data= """{
"item": {
    "allInventory": {
        "onHand": 64,
        "total": {
            "1000": 0,
            "1001": 6,
            "1002": 5,
            "1003": 3,
            "1004": 12,
            "1005": 0
        }
    }
},
"image": {
    "tag": "/828402de-6cc8-493e-8abd-935a48a3d766_1.285a6f66ecf3ee434100921a3911ce6c.jpeg?odnHeight=450&odnWidth=450&odnBg=FFFFFF"
 }
}"""
>>> data = json.loads(data)
>>> print data["item"]["allInventory"]["total"]
{'1005': 0, '1004': 12, '1003': 3, '1002': 5, '1001': 6, '1000': 0}
```